# How to remove trailing slash when redirecting to a new page in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to modify URLs and redirect traffic to a new URL without a trailing slash.
Below is my current server block:

```
    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate     /path/to/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private/key.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        # redirects manually entered here: 
        location /long-url-1/ { return 301 https://example.com/short-url-1; }
        location /long-url-2/ { return 301 https://example.com/short-url-2; }

        # all other traffic should be redirected by the rule below:
        location / { return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; }
}
```

I want to modify the following location block:

```
    # all other traffic should be redirected by the rule below:
    location / { return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; }
```

so if the user enters:

```
https://www.example.com/unknown-url-1/ => (www + with slash) the rule should redirect to:  https://example.com/unknown-url-1 (non-www + no trailing slash)
```

Or if the user enters:

```
https://www.example.com/unknown-url-2 => (www + no slash) the rule should redirect to:  https://example.com/unknown-url-2 (non-www + no trailing slash)
```

I think there are two ways of doing it:

1. By implementing two location blocks, one for Url requests with slash and one for all URLs without the slash, e.g:

```
    location / { rewrite ^/(.*)/?$ https://example.com/$1 permanent;}
    location ~* /(.*)/$ { return 301 https://example.com/$1;}
```

2. By adding a rewrite inside my existing location block and modifying the `$request_uri` somehow, eg:

```
location / { 
 rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 break;
 return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; 
}
```

Obviously, the above snippets don't work and I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `rewrite` to remove the trailing `/`. But in your example, the first capture is too greedy. Use `*?` for the lazy quantifier.

For example:

```
location / { 
    rewrite ^(/.*?)/?$ https://example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! You are the best @RichardSmith :)! One last question, If a similar rule needs to be applied to the proxy_path, would it be similar to this?     ```location / {
         rewrite ^(/.*?)/?$ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     }```

Comment: You have captured the leading `/`, so you should use `$1` and not `/$1`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites

```
location ~ (?<no_slash>.*)/$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$no_slash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution has also been tested and works well.

It should have a better performance because there is no rewriting according to the best practice above.

```
location ~ (.*?\/)(\/+)$ {
  return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;
}
```